# How to save RadioGroup State using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, radio-group

i have created a radio group which represents a question and has 4 answer choices (a , b , c , and d ) , hence i created 4 radio buttons for the radiogroup , and it worked fine , but what i want is to keep the answer checked when i leave the activity and return back to it , here is the code :

public class P2 extends Page1 {

```
RadioGroup rg2 ;
RadioButton r2a , r2b , r2c , r2d ;
Button b2n , b2b ;
TextView tv ;
int count ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_p2);

    rg2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG2);
    r2a = (RadioButton) rg2.getChildAt(0);
    r2b = (RadioButton) rg2.getChildAt(1);
    r2c = (RadioButton) rg2.getChildAt(2);
    r2d = (RadioButton) rg2.getChildAt(3);
    b2n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B2n);  // next button
    b2b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B2b); // back button to page1
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);


    rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
            if (r2c.isChecked()){
    count ++ ;  // since c is the correct answer add 1 to count (mark)

                          }

        }

    });


}
```

public void move21(View view) {  // called when b2b is clicked to go back to page1

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , Page1.class) ;
    startActivity (intent) ;
} }
```

BTW,  i did not define id's for the radiobuttons , just the id (rg2) for the radiogroup . 
how can i save the state of the radiogroup using shared preferences ? 
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do before you leave the current activity is save the state with something like:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("answers", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("r2a",r2a.isChecked());
editor.putBoolean("r2b",r2b.isChecked());
editor.putBoolean("r2c",r2c.isChecked());
editor.putBoolean("r2d",r2d.isChecked());
editor.apply();
```

Then, when you come back to the activity, you can do:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("answers", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean r2achecked = settings.getBoolean("r2a",false);
boolean r2bchecked = settings.getBoolean("r2b",false);
boolean r2cchecked = settings.getBoolean("r2c",false);
boolean r2dchecked = settings.getBoolean("r2d",false);
```

Then check each of those newly created `bool`s and if one of them is true, set that button to checked.